# c binary tree insert function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I am trying to make a binary tree program where each tree node contains a struct of 'inventory'.

I am currently getting an error in my insert function that causes compile to fail.
The error I am getting is:

```
left of '.invPartNo' must have class/struct/union
type is 'inventory *'
did you intend to use '->' instead?
```

These are my structures:

```
//inventory definition
typedef struct inventory
{
    char invName[36];
    int  invPartNo;
    int  invQOH;
    float invUnitCost;
    float invPrice;
}item;

//tree definition
struct btree {
    item *data;
    struct btree *left;
    struct btree *right;
} ;
```

And this is my insert code, where I did use ->, so I don't understand the error I'm getting. Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct btree *Insert(btree *node, inventory *i)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        btree *temp;
        temp = (btree *)malloc(sizeof(btree));
        temp->data = i;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    if(i.invPartNo > node->data->invPartNo) //error here
    {
        node->right = Insert(node->right, i);
    }
    else if(i.invPartNo < node->data->invPartNo) //error here
    {
        node->left = Insert(node->left, i);
    }
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of `i` is `inventory *` so you should replace `i.invPartNo` with `(*i).invPartNo` or equivalent `i->invPartNo` to resolve your error.

operator `.` is applicable for `struct objects` and **not** `pointers to struct object`. Operator `*` dereferences the pointer and dereferenced type is same `struct object` enabling the use of `.` here. But `(*i).memb` is noicy, so `C language syntax` provide a shortcut equivalent for the same as `i->mem`.

Comment: Thank you. That lets me compile now.